# jQuery: Create Automatic Timer for Slideshow - Cancel on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, timer, slider

So, I have a slideshow functional. This is my first slideshow with jQuery without using additional plugins. It is VERY basic and hard coded (which shouldn't be a problem I hope).

**I want to achieve an automatic scrolling effect every 8 seconds to the next item, then skip to the beginning at the end. I have an IDEA how to do it, but I wanted to achieve best practice with my design**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideWrap">
<div id="slides">
    <ul id="slidePane">
        <li><img src="css/images/slides/slide1.png" alt="img1" /></li>
        <li><img src="css/images/slides/slide2.png" alt="img2" /></li>
        <li><img src="css/images/slides/slide3.png" alt="img3" /></li>
        <li><img src="css/images/slides/slide4.png" alt="img4" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="slideNav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><h2>Packages</h2></li>
        <li><h2>Portfolio</h2></li>
        <li><h2>Prices</h2></li>
        <li><h2>About</h2></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
(function() {
var slider = $('#slides'),
        imgWid = $('ul#slidePane img').width(),
        imgHeight = -300,
        imgs = 4,
        imgsHeight = 3200; 

$('#slideNav ul li').on('click', function() {
        var listSel = $(this),
            selImg = $('#slideNav li').index(this);

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
        slider.animate({
            'margin-top': imgHeight * selImg
        });
    });
})();
</script>
```

- How and or where would I apply a feature where it just auto scrolls through the items vertically 1 by 1 until something is clicked on (in which case the auto feature stops)? *

Live Host:

http://www.sinsysonline.com/design

Please let me know if you'd like my css. I feel it's irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I'll just do it the old fashioned, longhand way. Was just looking for an easier way :-( I'll post results here.